# Vector insert function not inserting from the range specified

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to insert elements from an array into itself, but it's inserting variables randomly. Why is it not working as intended?

The function is inserting from wrong places for two instances that I have found.

when both iterators point to the same element

input array

`[1,2,3]`

array after insert

`[2,1,2,3]`

expected behavior

`[3,1,2,3]`

once where elements span two elements

input array

`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

array after insert

`[3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6]`

expected behavior

`[5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]`

here's the whole code

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        k= k % nums.size();
        // if(k==1) nums.insert(nums.begin(),nums.back());
        nums.insert(nums.begin(), nums.end()-k, nums.end());
        for (auto c:nums) cout << c << ",";
        nums.erase(nums.end() - k, nums.end());
    }
};
```

Note: It's working for a few cases of `k=2` but not this one

Edit: So the k=2 case is not working specifically for two input arrays that I came across while testing

`[1,2,3,4,5,6]` & `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Nice story. What is the question?

Comment: If you want to rotate elements in a container I suggest you try [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: @Blastfurnace I am practicing these DSA questions to build and understand logic. So using in built functions would not be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector::insert(pos, first, last)` cannot be used when `first` and `last` are iterators to the same vector as `pos`.

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), specifically - *The behavior is undefined if first and last are iterators into *this.*

Comment: thanks for the answer, I missed that part in the documentation. Could you guide me to why it's not working in the k=2 case, it's the only case where even tho the first and last iterators are not same it's showing a similart kind of behaviour.

Comment: @EffDuBois There is no "why" - undefined behaviour means the compiler is free to do anything and everything as-if the case cannot occur. It's likely just how the implementation accesses memory, that it works sometimes, and sometimes not.
The former cases working are actually the outliers, you cannot rely on this and should use a different algorithm.

Comment: @Juliean I was referring to the case k=2 where the two iterators point to different vectors, I was asking why it is not working since the documentation don't mention this edge case.

Comment: @EffDuBois How does k=2 make two iterators point to **different vectors**? There is only one vector here, "nums", and any iterator you aquire from that is an iterator that cannot be safely passed to nums.insert, as by the standard. Is there something missing from the code you have shown?

Comment: @EffDuBois I think you are confusing different vectors with different iterator values. All your examples involve iterators pointing at the same vector, therefore they are all invalid.

Comment: @john thanks a lot, I understand it now, I was confusing vector vs iterator